# groupBy on laravel

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, laravel-8

```
$tren = DB::table('suka')
                ->join('buku', 'buku.ISBN', '=', 'suka.ISBN')
                ->join('user', 'user.id_user', '=', 'suka.id_user')
                 ->raw('count(*) as total')
                 ->groupBy('suka.ISBN')
                 ->orderBy('maximum')
                 ->LIMIT(2)
                 ->get();
```

I want to group a join table by ISBN and then find the maximum count of them and take 2 of the most.

here is the error message

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::groupBy()
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there a specific error message you are trying to understand?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::groupBy()

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think your error is because of your raw call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one ISBN column in the result set (because it exists in multiple tables). You should specify which table's ISBN column you want to group by in your group by call.

Also, try calling selectRaw instead of raw:

```
->selectRaw('count(*) as total')
```

You can read more about raw queries in [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions).